# JavaScript - Get the unique object from array of objects

Tags: javascript

```
let obj = [
    { id : 1 },
    { id : 10 },
    { brand : 12 },
    { id : 15 },
    { id : 18 },
    { image_link : 'some link' },
    { price : 10 },
    { brand : 111 },
    { image_link : 'some link 2' }
];
```

I have this array of object. I want filter this object so that I can get an object without duplicate keys.

**I am trying this:**

```
let uniqueIds = [];

let unique = obj.filter( (element ) => {
    
    let key = Object.keys(element)[0];                
    let isDuplicate = uniqueIds.includes(element.key);

    if (!isDuplicate) {
        uniqueIds.push(element.key);
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
});

console.log( unique )
```

But everytime it's showing me :

```
[ { id: 1 } ]
```

**My expected output:**

```
[
    { id : 18 },
    { price : 10 },
    { brand : 111 },
    { image_link : 'some link 2' }
];
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: `brnad` is not `brand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter your array based on whether the object's key is the last occurrence of that key (checked using [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)) in the array:

```js
let obj = [
    { id : 1 },
    { id : 10 },
    { brand : 12 },
    { id : 15 },
    { id : 18 },
    { image_link : 'some link' },
    { price : 10 },
    { brand : 111 },
    { image_link : 'some link 2' }
];

const keys = obj.map(o => Object.keys(o)[0])

const result = obj.filter((o, i) => keys.lastIndexOf(Object.keys(o)[0]) == i)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I have added my exptected output on my question. Can you check it please?

Comment: @Shibbir please see my edit, that matches your required output

Comment: @Shibbir good to hear! :)

Comment: one more help. Can I remove the keys which value is empty?

Comment: @Shibbir you could pre-filter `obj` i.e. `obj = obj.filter(o => Object.values(o)[0])` *before* you generate `keys` and `result`

Comment: Do you mean this: https://codeshare.io/AdVxbE? It's not working then.

Comment: @Shibbir sorry, I misinterpreted what you wanted. I thought for that sample data you would want `{ id : 18 }` in the output instead of `{ id : '' }`, not to remove `id` completely. In that case you should add the filter on `result` instead i.e. `const result = obj.filter((o, i) => keys.lastIndexOf(Object.keys(o)[0]) == i).filter(o => Object.values(o)[0])`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you need to use `key` instead of `element.key`

Note: it seems you have a typo `brnad` is not `brand`

```js
let obj = [
    { id : 1 },
    { id : 10 },
    { brand : 12 },
    { id : 15 },
    { id : 18 },
    { image_link : 'some link' },
    { price : 10 },
    { brand : 111 },
    { image_link : 'some link 2' }
];

let uniqueIds = [];
let unique = obj.filter( (element ) => {
    
    let key = Object.keys(element)[0];                
    let isDuplicate = uniqueIds.includes(key);

    if (!isDuplicate) {
       uniqueIds.push(key);
       return true;
    }
    return false;   
});

console.log( unique )
```

Comment: I have added my exptected output on my question. Can you check it please?

Comment: @Shibbir I change `brnad` to `brand`, you can check it now again

Comment: Can you please check my exptected output on my questions?

Comment: @Shibbir so you want to the latter key to override previous,in this case `forEach` might be a better choice or as Nick's answer

Answer (score 0):

You have used `element.key` in two places it should be just `key`.

And since you need the final duplicate element you need to do a reverse of the input array and again do another reverse to unique array.

```js
let obj = [
  { id : 1 },
  { id : 10 },
  { brand : 12 },
  { id : 15 },
  { id : 18 },
  { image_link : 'some link' },
  { price : 10 },
  { brand : 111 },
  { image_link : 'some link 2' }
];

let uniqueIds = [];

// reverse the input array before start filtering
obj.reverse()

let unique = obj.filter( (element ) => {
    
    let key = Object.keys(element)[0];                
    let isDuplicate = uniqueIds.includes(key);

    if (!isDuplicate) {
        uniqueIds.push(key);
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
});
// to make the output order according to the input array
unique.reverse()
// to make the input array to the initial order 
obj.reverse()

console.log(unique)
```

Comment: id should be 18